# C++ What is the best data structure for a two dimensional array of object "piles"?

Tags: arrays, vector, multidimensional-array, grid, collision

The size of the grid will be known at the start (but will be different each time the program starts). However, the DEPTH of each cell is not a mere value, but rather a population of objects that will vary constantly during runtime.

Q: What is the most recommended (efficient and easy to maintain; less prone to user error) way of implementing this ?

- Is this some kind of a standard 2D array of vector pointers ?
- Is it a 3D Vector array ?
- Is it a 2D array of linked lists, or binary trees (I am thinking binary trees will add complexity overhead because of continuous deletion and insertion node-gymnastics)
- Is it some other custom data structure ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe you could describe your actual application.  Do you need to iterate through these piles, or do you just need to count the height of each pile?  If you have a fixed set of nodes, you could simply store the grid position in the node and update a depth histogram.  When you move a node, you just do two histogram updates and change the grid position.  Not sure if that's useful.  As I say, depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: It's a collision grid table. Each cell contains references to a variable number of objects. So we are dealing with thousands of searches, deletions and additions per millisecond. However, there should be no more than about 5 or 10 objects per cell (we would rather make the grid finer to reduce the number of objects per cell)

Comment: Well, try it out with storing a vector in each cell.  In most cases, a vector is better than a list.  Sounds a bit like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14615449/1553090) I gave a while back.  If you need to get quicker and dirtier, you can memory-pool the vectors.  Maybe even use vectors as a second-resort.  You might want to experiment with storing small local arrays inline and then spilling over to a vector, so you keep most of your memory accesses local.  In that respect, blocking your grid into pages might also help to improve locality.

Answer (score 2):

Use a 1D array for best cache locality.  A `vector` would be fine for this.

```
std::vector<int> histdata( width * height );
```

If you need to index the rows quickly, then make something to point into it:

```
std::vector<int*> histogram( height );
histogram[0] = &histdata[0];
for( int i = 1; i < height; i++ ) {
    histogram[i] = histogram[i-1] + width;
}
```

Now you have a 2D histogram stored in a 1D vector.  You can access it like this:

```
histogram[row][col]++;
```

If you wrap all this up in a simple class, you're less likely to do something silly with the pointers.  You can also make a `clear()` function to set the histogram data to zero (which just rips through the `histdata` vector and zeros it).

Comment: the depth of each cell is not a mere value. It's a population of objects that will vary constantly during runtime.

Comment: I'd hardly call it a histogram in that case.  Anyway, that's fine.  Just `typedef std::vector<MyObject> Objects` and replace `int` with `Objects` in the example above.  Then every cell has a vector that you can populate with your items.